# Class 'Yajra\DataTables\DatatablesServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I've developed Laravel Project in my local computer.
I used Yajra Pakagebox for using bootstrap datatables on it.

Like this :
**composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
php artisan vendor:publish**

Then I pushed them all into Hosting Server but it displays errors like below.

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'Yajra\DataTables\DatatablesServiceProvider' not found
in ProviderRepository.php (line 208)
at ProviderRepository->createProvider('Yajra\\DataTables\\DatatablesServiceProvider')
in ProviderRepository.php (line 144)
at ProviderRepository->compileManifest(array('Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Cookie\\CookieServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\FoundationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Hashing\\HashServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Pagination\\PaginationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Pipeline\\PipelineServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Auth\\Passwords\\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Session\\SessionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Translation\\TranslationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\\View\\ViewServiceProvider', 'Yajra\\DataTables\\DatatablesServiceProvider', 'Laravel\\Tinker\\TinkerServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider', 'App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider'))
in ProviderRepository.php (line 61)
```

The important thing is I can't execute any command on Hosting Server because it is Shared Hosting Server.
I saw many articles for solving this problem but they are all using "artisan" and "composer" command.
But I can't use this command at all.
I can only upload the source code to server with FTP.

Comment: did you try to `composer-dumpautoload`, clear composer and framework cache(on local), and then reupload to server?

Comment: It seems to me that you haven't added the service provider to the `$providers` array in `config/app.php`

Answer (score 11):

Depending on what version of DataTables you are using, it may be simple capitalization issue.  After version 8 you should use:

```
Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider
```

Before version 8 use:

```
Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider
```

Upgrade notes reference: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/upgrade#namespace

Comment: I was doing a copy paste from a tutorial that used capitols for L8, but I'm working in L5.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Please run below command and try:

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload

php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: I can't access Hosting Server with SSH.

Comment: I Can't Use "Composer" or "Artisan" because I can't access to Hosting Server with SSH. So I uploaded all source. Please Help Me.

Comment: Thanks, I think some of the dependencies cause this problem to happen, I have run all the above script and it works! *P/S: I deleted vendor folder too.

Answer (score 6):

It is working for v@8.3

```
Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
'Datatables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
```

Please add this to the config/app.php file.
The first line goes under the "Package Service Providers" section
and the second line goes under the "Class Aliases" section

Answer (score 2):

replace `Datatables` with `DataTables`

Answer (score 2):

In the project's folder

```
rm -R vendor/
rm -R bootstrap/cache
mkdir bootstrap/cache
chmod -R 777 bootstrap/*
```

if your laravel version => 5.4

`composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"~8.0"`

if your laravel version => 5.8

`composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"~9.0"`

```
@config/app.php
'providers' => [
    ...,
    Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
]

'aliases' => [
    ...,
    'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
]

composer dumpautoload
composer install
```

It works for me.

Source: [https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables[https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables][1]](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables%5Bhttps://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables%5D%5B1%5D)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, please make sure to put code in ```code boxes```

Answer (score 2):

**REASON ITS NOT WORKING IS:**

you installed the library. and added it in config/app.php in providers array.

don't forget to run

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

after that.

Answer (score 1):

Re install with the plugin along with the buttons plugin and now it's working.
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons:^3.0

Answer (score 0):

**Try below steps to resolve this issue:**

1. Use composer show to check which version of packages you are using.
2. Delete all files under bootstrap/cache folder
3. Delete vendor folder and reinstall all packages using composer install.

Comment: I Can't Use "Composer" or "Artisan" because I can't access to Hosting Server with SSH. So I uploaded all source. Please Help Me

Comment: Do this locally and upload through ftp?

Answer (score 0):

all the files you know you're changing to ftp (migrations config controller...)

and replaced local files to server with ftp

```
/composer.json
/composer.lock
/bootstrap/*
/storage/framework/cache/*
/storage/framework/views/*
/vendor/composer/*
/vendor/autoload.php
```

If the problem persists, I'm need to relay the version of the Laravel.
Tested with

```
php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 5.4.19
```

Comment: I can't use any shell command like "artisan" and "composer". Please help me.

Comment: I uploaded completely all source in my local computer.

Comment: @LeeDaniel there is no other solution if it works properly on your local computer and you need to work if you are uploading this working state to the server. And you can use call artisan commands with Artisan::call() in your temp controller. See at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Answer (score 0):

In your [config/app.php] file, edit the aliases array. Change it from

```
'Datatables' => Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables::class
```

to

```
'Datatables' => Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class
```